# How can I replace a template file in an Ansible role?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, ansible-galaxy

Some Ansible roles, such as https://github.com/bertvv/ansible-role-hosts, use template files that may be a near miss for the needs of this project. When the role author has not provided a variable substitution for the name of the template, is there still a way to replace the template file? Obviously, I could fork the role and use my own fork, but I'm hoping there's a better answer, such as "just drop your replacement template file in the templates directory of your role that depends on Bert's role."

Comment: There's really no other solution other than locally editing either the template or the corresponding task (e.g., to have the task use an alternate template).

Answer (score 4):

[Playbook pathing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html) has some "do what I mean" magic for relative paths.  `rolename/templates` is searched first in dependency order, then `{{playbook_dir}}/templates`

You cannot change this without altering the role somehow, one of:

- altering the src file name
- adding a dependency on your role that provides a different template of the same name
- editing their template

I like changing the file name the best. Send them a change that make the source template name into a variable in role defaults.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to have changes occur at every ansible run you could use a `lineinfile` task on the instantiated template file (i.e. the `dest` in the `template` task) after the role is applied.

Comment: Not willing, but I agree that your answer is accurate.